# Template in Django doesn't show same content for 2 paths

Tags: python, django

For this template,  everything will show fine, but only for the first course. If I add lectures for another course, template won't show them.

```css
def courses(request, slug):
    con = get_object_or_404(Course, slug=slug)
    context = {
        'course': con,
        'lectures': con.lectures.all(),
        'categories': con.categories.all(),
    }
    return render(request, 'courses/courses.html', context)
```

```html
<ul>
        {% for a in categories %}
            <li><strong>{{ a.course_category }}</strong></li>
            {% for c in lectures %}
                {% if a == c.course_category %}
                    <li>{{ c.lecture_title }}</li>
                    <li>{{ c.content }}</li>
                    {% if c.link %}
                        <li>{{ c.link }}</li>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if c.file %}
                        <li><a href='{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ c.file.url }}'>download</a></li>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

```html
class Course(models.Model):
    study_programme = models.ForeignKey('StudyProgramme', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ects = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(99)])
    description = models.TextField()
    year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(99)])
    semester = models.IntegerField(choices=((1, "1"),
                                            (2, "2"),
                                            ), default=None)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=140, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def _get_unique_slug(self):
        slug = slugify(self.name)
        unique_slug = slug
        num = 1
        while Course.objects.filter(slug=unique_slug).exists():
            unique_slug = '{}-{}'.format(slug, num)
            num += 1
        return unique_slug

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = self._get_unique_slug()
        super().save()

class CourseCategory(models.Model):
course = models.ForeignKey('Course', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='categories')
course_category = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.course_category


class Lecture(models.Model):
course = models.ForeignKey('Course', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='', related_name='lectures')
```

This is the Course model that is present in my models.py. It uses slug for links.

Comment: wouldn't this line `con = get_object_or_404(Course, slug=slug)` only retrieve one object? Have you tried something like `Course.objects.filter(slug=slug).all()`?

Comment: Now I get this: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'lectures'

Comment: can you post your Course model?

Comment: @joppich I edited the post now.

Comment: your lecture and category models related to Course model by Foreignkey? Then it must work... weird. Now you got 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'lectures' too? Can you post your Lecture and Category models too?

Comment: Done it. Check it please.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `Lecture` model has a problem.

Why does your `Lecture` model's course field has `default=''`?

It should be one of your `Courcse` model objects. If you want to add default value, you can use like this

```
DEFAULT_COURSE = 1
class Lecture(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey('Course', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=DEFAULT_COURSE, related_name='lectures')
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with my lecture class.  Also it had more attributes, I just didnt want to show them cuz they are not relevant. Problem is, my best guess, between the view and objects.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

You need two views for this, each doing only the database queries they actually need and handle all the data preparation.
This way, you get nice and clean templates.

**First View:** `/courses`

```
def courses(request):
    queryset = Course.objects.all()
    context = {'courses':queryset}
    return render(request, 'courses/courses.html', context)
```

template for this (courses.html):

```
<ul>
{% for i in courses %}
    <li>
        <a href={{ i.slug }}>{{ i }}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**Second View:** `/courses/course_name`

```
def course_detail(request, course_name):
    query = Course.object.get(name=course_name)
    context = {'lectures':query.lectures.all(),'categories':query.categories.all()}
    return render(request, 'courses/course_detail.html', context)
```

template for this (course_detail.html):

```
<p><strong>Categories</strong></p>
<ul>
    {% for c in categories %}
        <li>{{ c.course_category }}<li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
<p><strong>Lectures</strong></p>
<ul>
    {% for l in lectures %}
        <li>{{ l.lecture_title }}</li>
        <li>{{ l.content }}</li>
        {% if l.link %}
            <li>{{ l.link }}</li>
        {% endif %}
        {% if l.file %}
            <li><a href='{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ l.file.url }}'>download</a></li>
        {% endif %}
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Now I dont get it.. course its not even rendered anymore. Could u edit template as well or provide a better explanation ?

Comment: changed the retrieval a little and edited how to template.

Comment: if you filter your query by a unique value, you will only ever get one result... updated my answer. also, [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects) should help for future reference

Comment: Ok, this is might be working, excepting one  thing:  now all the courses list the lectures of the first course..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163412/discussion-between-joppich-and-dann-m).